# Eclipse CDT with GNU ARM EABI

Tags: windows, arm, eclipse-cdt, stm32, eabi

I have built an environment. I tend to get the file format not recognized while linking. 
I have enabled the verbose please let me know if anyone has an answer for this.

> 01:14:38 **** Build of configuration Debug for project testerr ****
>   make -j all 
>   'Building target: testerr.elf'
>   'Invoking: Cross ARM C Linker'
>   arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker --print-gc-sections -s -Wl,-Map,"testerr.map" -Xlinker --cref -v -o "testerr.elf"  ./Src/main.o ./Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o ./Src/stm32f4xx_it.o  ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_adc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_adc_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_can.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_crc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cryp.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cryp_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dac.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dac_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dcmi.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma2d.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_eth.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_hash.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_hash_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_hcd.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2s.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2s_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_irda.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_iwdg.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_ltdc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp_template.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_nand.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_nor.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pccard.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rng.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rtc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rtc_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sai.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sd.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sdram.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_smartcard.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sram.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_usart.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_wwdg.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_fmc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_fsmc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_sdmmc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o  ./Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32f4xx.o
>   Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program\ files\ (x86)/gnu\ tools\ arm\ embedded/4.8\ 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: arm-none-eabi
>   Configured with: /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/gcc/configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw --libexecdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw/lib --infodir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-headers=yes --with-newlib --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-mingw/arm-none-eabi --with-libiconv-prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-gmp=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-cloog=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-mingw/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors' --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,armv7-r
>   Thread model: single
>   gcc version 4.8.4 20140526 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 211358] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 
>   COMPILER_PATH=c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/
>   LIBRARY_PATH=c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/armv7-m/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/;c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/
>   COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mcpu=cortex-m3' '-mthumb' '-O0' '-fmessage-length=0' '-fsigned-char' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-g3' '-nostartfiles' '-nodefaultlibs' '-nostdlib' '-s' '-v' '-o' 'testerr.elf'
>    c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/collect2.exe --sysroot=c:\program files (x86)\gnu tools arm embedded\4.8 2014q2\bin../arm-none-eabi -X -o testerr.elf -s -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/armv7-m -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4 -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib -Lc:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.8 2014q2/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib --gc-sections --print-gc-sections -Map testerr.map --cref ./Src/main.o ./Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o ./Src/stm32f4xx_it.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_adc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_adc_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_can.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_crc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cryp.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cryp_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dac.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dac_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dcmi.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma2d.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_eth.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_hash.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_hash_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_hcd.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2s.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_i2s_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_irda.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_iwdg.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_ltdc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp_template.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_nand.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_nor.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pccard.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rng.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rtc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_rtc_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sai.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sd.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sdram.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_smartcard.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_sram.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_usart.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_wwdg.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_fmc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_fsmc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_sdmmc.o ./Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o ./Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32f4xx.o
>   ./Src/main.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [testerr.elf] Error 1

01:14:39 Build Finished (took 627ms)

Comment: The error is caused by an earlier phase of build - compilation of source into main.o. Try to make your example smaller and post full compilation build here. Also try not to mess formatting that much, as the log you posted is really hard to read...

Comment: this build is a copy paste I have not changed any formatting. I did not understand when u said the error was caused by earlier phase of build. Can you please explain ?

Comment: What you pasted doesn't give much info, as the problem is the compilation step of main.c (or .cpp or whatever) into main.o. Do a clean, do full rebuild, paste the full log somewhere (pastebin or sth like that) and add the link here. The log you currently posted says what is says and nothing more - main.o file is not a valid object file. There's no way to find out why from only this info above. Ideally remove whole SPL from the project, as this is not relevant to the problem and only adds noise to the log.

Comment: While you're correcting things, you might want to change your `-mcpu=cortex-m3` to `-mcpu=cortex-m4`